# If $A$ and $B$ are skew-symmetric, then $A^2BA$ is symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

Let $A$ and $B$ be skew-symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices. That is, $A^t = -A$ and $B^t = -B$.

According to WolframAlpha, $A^2BA$ is a symmetric matrix. I believe there is an easier way to prove this fact than directly computing the matrix $A^2BA$. I tried
$$ (A^2BA)^t = A^t B^t (A^t)^2 = ABA^2, $$
but it does not help. Could you help me? Thank you.

---

(Edit) Thanks to @BrunoB, I corrected my input.

Using [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D.%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D.%7B%7B0%2C-f%2Ce%7D%2C%7Bf%2C0%2C-d%7D%2C%7B-e%2Cd%2C0%7D%7D.%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D), we have the following.

[image]

Comment: This is already a proof, but I guess you are looking for a more elegant one.

Comment: There's no way the formula given by Wolfram Alpha here would be that simple right? Looks like it only did multiplication component by component...

Comment: @BrunoB WolframAlpha does matrix multiplication. E.g., https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D%5E2

Comment: Apparently, we have to show that $ABA$ commutes with $A$. What can we say about $ABA$ ?

Comment: @BrunoB I do not understand this comment. Wolfram Alpha just calculates this matrix product and this proves the above claim.

Comment: @Peter It seems like you need $.$ to indicate a matrix multiplication, see this [(link)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/LinearAlgebra.html) at the section "Multiplying Vectors and Matrices" (this gives a different result, as seen [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D%5E2.%7B%7B0%2C-f%2Ce%7D%2C%7Bf%2C0%2C-d%7D%2C%7B-e%2Cd%2C0%7D%7D.%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D))

Comment: prove its transpose is equal to $BAA^2$

Comment: @BrunoB You are right ! The resulting matrix is much more complicated, however actually symmtetric.

Comment: Actually the correct thing is [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%28%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D%5E2%29+.+%7B%7B0%2C-f%2Ce%7D%2C%7Bf%2C0%2C-d%7D%2C%7B-e%2Cd%2C0%7D%7D.%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D), didn't realise you'd need parentheses around the squared matrix in the formula, my bad (sadly can't change the second link in my previous comment since five minutes passed, but I guess it's informative that it yields yet another result?).

Comment: @BrunoB I did not know that. Thank you! By the way, I think the correct one is this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D+%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D+%7B%7B0%2C-f%2Ce%7D%2C%7Bf%2C0%2C-d%7D%2C%7B-e%2Cd%2C0%7D%7D+%7B%7B0%2C-c%2Cb%7D%2C%7Bc%2C0%2C-a%7D%2C%7B-b%2Ca%2C0%7D%7D

Comment: Oh that's wack... I guess the square messes up something. After further reading of the first link I posted it does seem like for matrix powers you need to write "MatrixPower[M,k]" huh. Still want to know why we now have four totally different results (though at least one is correct now!) haha

Comment: @BrunoB Yes, it seems we should be careful when using powers. Interestingly, still the matrix is symmetric, and my question is valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$A(x)=a\times x$ and $B(x)=b\times x$ for some vectors $a,b.$

$ABA(x)=-(b\cdot a)(a\times x).$

Whence $ABA$ commutes with $A.$

Comment: @Peter (I think you were the downvoter): what do you advise me to improve my answer?